# How to drink in a cold environment?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

In Dwarf Fortress adventure mode, how can I drink? My waterskin is full of ice. I did find a well, but the bucket is also full of ice. Is there a way to melt it by a campfire? Licking it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Watch the licking. I wouldn't put it past DF to have a module that checks if your tongue sticks to the ice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Toady mentions his "hackneyed" solution to this in the dev blog and then in the release notes, but it's not obvious.

- ability to make campfire (from 'g') and warm items at campfire/fire/magma (from 'I') in adv mode

What you have to do is make a campfire and then warm your water skin at it until it turns to liquid, and then you can drink from it.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I didn't even know about `I`nteract and had tried to heat the water with `l`ook and `u`se.